# DTYPE Column discriminator as a Catalog class

Tags: java, jpa, jpql

I everyone, I have the following

A user can have multiples profiles but each profile has its own function so I will have just one user entry and multiples roles entries

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USER", indexes = {
        @Index(unique = false, columnList = "NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL")})
public class USER implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "USER_SEQ", sequenceName = "USER_SEQ", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "USER_SEQ")
    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID_USER")
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "NAME")
    private String name;
    @Column(name = "LAST_NAME")
    private String lastName;
    @Column(name = "EMAIL")
    private String email;
    // getters and setters
}
```

A parent class for each profile

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public abstract class Profile implements Serializable {

    @SequenceGenerator(name = "PROFILE_SEQ", sequenceName = "PROFILE_SEQ", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "PROFILE_SEQ")
    @Id
    private Long idProfile;
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private User user;

    //getters and setters

}
```

At least two son classes

```
@Entity
public class Administrator extends Profile{

}

@Entity
public class Regional extends Profile {

    public Regional () {
    }

    private Long idAsignedRegion;
    //getters and setters

}
```

So far I can select all of them or by specific profile, but now I want to have something in the front end for example a .xhtml page and I wish to have a select component representing all the DTYPES availables as objects in order to generate a strategy method for resolve at runtime each user/profile that the user enters

So my specifics questions are two

1. Is there a way to get all the DTYPES availables in order to treat them as a catalog?
2. Or there is a way to specify the DTYPE as a reference of a catalog?

Something like this

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@DiscriminatorColumn(discriminatorType = ProfileCatalog.class, value="idProfileCatalog")
public abstract class Profile implements Serializable
```

Thanks!